# Dismiss UITextField decimal pad keyboard in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield, dismiss

I'm looking for a solution to my problem but all the suggestions I've found are not working.

I started with a working solution that is based on two `TextField` with decimal pad. To dismiss the keyboard when is tapped anywhere, considering i do not have the return key, I used successfully:

```
view.endEditing(true)
```

My problem stars when I decide to add `UIScrollView` in order to move up the `UITextField` on the bottom of the screen.

The view.endEditing(true) is not working because the scrollview is covering view. I add a `TapGestureRecognizer` and everything work except the keyboard dismiss.

Under the `TapGestureReconizer` function if I use `resignFirstResponder` on the `activeTextFiled` the app crash going to `AppDelegate` with error:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var activeField: UITextField?

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldTop: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldBottom: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        activeField = textField
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        activeField = nil
    } 

    func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillBeHidden", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func deregisterFromKeyBoardNotification() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
        self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
        let info : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height + 20, 0.0)

        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
        if let _ = activeField
        {
            if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField!.frame.origin))
            {
                self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField!.frame, animated: true)
            }
        }
        self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    }

    func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification)
    {
        let info : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)
        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        registerForKeyboardNotifications()
        self.textFieldBottom.delegate = self
        self.textFieldTop.delegate = self

        scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "closeKeyboard"))

    }

    func closeKeyboard() {
        activeField?.resignFirstResponder()

    }
}
```

I've tried different solution but none of them are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was still looking to some delegate or other possible missing part in the code/storyboard but spending additional hours checking I found the problem.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillBeHidden:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

I forgot in the original code the ":" at the end of "keyboardWillBeHidden:".
This was throwing an exception because this function has an argument.

Now everything is working properly